# How to get HTTP JSON-response into HTML (Ionic2, Angular2, TypeScript, PHP, JSON)?

Tags: html, json, api, angular, typescript

I am currently working on my first Ionic 2 app, but I am not yet very much into typescript..

I want to call the authenticate() method in my constructor and afterwards to

1. get the whole JSON response into the textarea
   and/or
2. access the username and password value of the json response in my HTML

TypeScript:

```
export class WelcomePage {
    public data: string;
    username: string;
    password: string;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public http: Http) {
        this.authenticate();
    }    

    authenticate() {
            var creds = { username: 'user1', password: 'pw1' };

            var headers = new Headers();
            headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

            this.http.post('http://www.xyz.api.php', creds, {
                headers: headers
            })
                .map(res => res.json())

                .subscribe(
                data => this.data,
                err => this.logError(err),
                () => console.log('Completed')
                );
        }
}
```

Response I already got from API:

```
 { "Person":[ {"Username":"user1","Password":"pw1"} ] }
```

HTML:

```
<textarea>here: {{data}}</textarea>
```

--> textarea is empty

Comment: The data is json object so you need to loop the object like this <div *ngFor="let item of data"><textarea>{{item.Username}}</textarea></div>

Comment: unfortunately it is still empty, no textareas appear

Comment: In Output screen are you getting [Object Object ]

Comment: there is no output at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would want to extract the object that is inside the array, which is inside `Person`:

```
.map(res => res.json().Person[0]) // extract object
```

Furthermore, you need to assign the data to `this.data` like so:

```
.subscribe(
   data => this.data = data // here!
   ....
```

Then use (together with the [**safe navigation operator**](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator) `?` here.)

`{{data?.Username}}` and `{{data?.Password}}`

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, adjusted the code, but textarea remains empty

Comment: have you tried `{{data | json}}` are you actually having values in `data`?

Comment: works now with your last changes, just had to restart ionic :) thanks very much, you made my day!

Comment: You are welcome, happy to help! Have a great day and happy coding :)